# Firefox 4 always freezes

Tags: firefox

I do not know if other users are experiencing this. But my firefox 4 installation always freezes (not responding) for about 10 seconds whenever I try to launch it.
Here are the extensions that I have:

- Session manager
- Grease Monkey
- WOT

Userscripts:

- Download youtube videos as mp4

Plugins:

- Flash

I'm currently at version 4.0.1. What can I do to solve this annoying problem?

Comment: Does it still freeze if you disable all your extensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Turn off all your extensions.

2) Switch them back on, one by one, until you identify the culprit.

3) Disable that extension.

4) ???

5) Profit.

Comment: How deep is this rabbit hole?